# Rolling a dice on unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on Unity  and I have recently wrote a dice rolling  code , but the dice falls in infinity instead of falling on the board, I do not add the problem in the code but in the modifications on unity, help me please

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can't help you without seeing your code and as it stands, I think this question is too broad for anyone to provide any meaningful help without just guessing.

Comment: well that can be an issue regarding rigid bodies or so! check that property of your board and dice  and also check colliders! I think thats pretty basic tardy every good coders get those tardies in UNITY

Comment: Please add more details of what is happening.

Comment: Flagged as unclear, your question contains no where enough information for someone to reliably pinpoint your problem and give you an answer that will suit your needs.  You can start by telling us the composition of your objects, like what kind of colliders do they have, do they have rigidbodies, does your scene contain something the dice is suppose to land on, what is that boards composition.  You say you didnt add the problem with code, but you also didn't say anything about your scene, nor the objects in it. If you arent using any of Unity's physics systems how are you dropping the dice.

Answer (score 1):

### There could be a lot of reasons.

Your question is a little light on the details, and arguable this kind of question should not be on stackoverflow as it is not code related. However here are the likely solutions to your problem.

There is really only one situation that can result in this, and that is that your dice are somehow not colliding with a surface. So you will be trying to figure out a reason for this.

1. Do you have something for the dice to land on? For example a plain or terrain? If there is nothing for it to land on then of course it will fall into infinity. So add an object for your dice to collide with.
2. Do your dice have a rigidbody and mesh collider? If they do not then they may be falling through other objects and hence falling into infinity. Whatever the dice are falling onto must also have these properties. So make sure your objects have a rigid body component and collider.
3. Your dice are positioned too low in relation to the object, and so are not hitting the mesh and are instead falling through. So position the dice higher.

Some tests:

Remove your code from the dice object and see if it still falls into infinity. If it does, you need to play around with objects before adding your code.

If this or other answers solved your issue don't forget to accept it. It is a courtesy to the community.

Comment: "Lots of reasons" -> Flag as "too broad."

Comment: @Draco18s True but sometimes, one issue can be caused by many reasons and listing them to save time does not mean "too broad". Althoug this question is missing so many information to be answered.

Comment: @PassetCronUs That's the exact definition of "too broad." The asker did not give enough detail in order to narrow down the cause, e.g. "I tried X and Y and that didn't help." They didn't show their scene hierarchy, their code, anything. What does too broad say? *Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with **enough detail** to identify an adequate answer.*

Answer (score 0):

Add "rigidbody" and "box collider" to your dice.
Add "box collider" or any other collider to your Board.

Easy peasy. If you do not change dice's transform position thru script this will work for sure. If you used, I suggest you use unity's physic system instead of changing an object's position thru script. That sometimes forcing objects to surpass collisions.

Comment: Even if you change the objects transform position through script, if the object has a rigidbody and collider, and the thing it is colliding with also has it, and it is moving smoothly then the objects generally won't move through each other. Instantaneous movement to a completely different location would be the exception.

Comment: @TylerSigi Actually it will, depending on how you are moving the transform,  if you are updating the transform in just update, and not a FixedUpdate(Which is drastically affected by the rate FixedUpdate gets called...) regardless of how smoothly you are moving it, it can go through the object, or cause an improper separation causing the object to appear to be "Bouncing" around.

Comment: I have mostly seen the bouncing around.